# Add parent node to a specific element xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to select Parent node without Child node.

Example:

```
<root>
    <p>some text</p>
    <ol>
      <li>
         <a href="http://cowherd.com" rel="nofollow">http://cowherd.com</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <p> <a href="http://cowherd.com" rel="nofollow">http://cowherd.com</a> </p>
    <a href="http://cowherd.com" rel="nofollow">http://cowherd.com</a>
</root>
```

Desired Output: I want to add a parent `<p>` tag to those `<a>` tags which don't have any parent except `<root>`.

```
<root>
    <p>some text</p>
    <ol>
      <li>
         <a href="http://cowherd.com" rel="nofollow">http://cowherd.com</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <p> <a href="http://cowherd.com" rel="nofollow">http://cowherd.com</a> </p>
    <p> <a href="http://cowherd.com" rel="nofollow">http://cowherd.com</a> <p>
</root>
```

I tried thi but it doesn't work. It adds the `<p>` tag around all `<a>` tags.

```
 <xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:if test="parent::*">
        <p><a>
            <!-- do not forget to copy possible other attributes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </a></p>
</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: In our question you say: "tag to those tags which don't have any parent except ."
What does `.` mean?

Comment: @Daniel Haley; you edited the question. How do know it’s the root-element?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed - I only added code formatting. `<root>` was already there it just wasn’t displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way this could be done :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="a[not(parent::p)]">
    <p>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93F8dVt

Comment: Your solution is adding p tag to all that a tags that don’t have p tag as it’s parent which is wrong

Comment: @rajatsethi from reading your question the exact requirement was not entirely clear to me, but you can get the idea from my answer and adapt to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I used your answer to fit my problem and it works. I have one more doubt in xslt as I’m new in this below is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800410/add-ol-ul-to-all-li-tags-that-doesnt-have-ol-ul-as-its-parent-xslt

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add a parent `<p>` tag to those `<a>` tags which don't have any parent except `<root>`.

I believe that boils down to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/a">
    <p>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996195/verify-href-has-a-valid-url-or-not-xslt-1?noredirect=1#comment127219728_71996195

Comment: Sure and sorry for asking your help out of my boundries. I just need some directions to work  on my problem. Still thanks for answering my other questions. Really appreciate that.