# Add <ol>/<ul> to all <li> tags that doesn't have <ol>/<ul> as it's parent XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this kind of xml where `some <li> tags` doesn't have `<ol>/<ul>` as it's parent. Need to add  as it's parent.

Example:

```
<root>
    <p>some text</p>
    <ol>
      <li>
         <a href="http://cowherd.com" rel="nofollow">http://cowherd.com</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>some text</li>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <li>some text in li.</li>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <li>some text in li.</li>
</root>
```

Desired Output: I want to add a parent `<ol>or<ul>` tag to those `<li>tags` which don't have it's parent `as <ol>/<ul>`. And also if there are continuesly more than one `<li> tag then all the <li> tags should come under same <ul>/<ol>just like below.` Thanks in advance.

```
<root>
    <p>some text</p>
    <ol>
      <li>
         <a href="http://cowherd.com" rel="nofollow">http://cowherd.com</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
      <li>some text</li>
      <li>some text</li>
    </ol>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <ol> 
      <li>some text in li.</li>
    </ol>
    <p>some more text</p>
    <ol>
      <li>some text in li.</li>
    </ol>
</root>
```

Comment: Look into any `for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent=". instance of element(li)"` examples, see [tag:xslt-grouping] and its info https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Comment: Can it be assumed that all `li` elements that need a parent `ol` are children of `root`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k it’s not mandatory that they are direct children of root. There can be scenarios in which they can be direct child of root but not everytime

Comment: @michael.hor257k i have tried some grouping thing in my xslt version 1 but no one fits the problem. If you have any example for the same that would be great. Thanks in advance. To be more clear i just need that li tags which don’t have parents as ol or ul

Comment: Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

To give you a start:

if those `li` without a parent `ol` can occur everywhere use this match:

```
  <xsl:template match="*[li[not(parent::lo)]]">
```

And like @Martin Honnen in his comment suggest make use of

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent=". instance of element(li)">
```

In that group-loop you can then make use of [`current-grouping-key()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-current-grouping-key) and [`current-group()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-current-group)

Comment: i’m not sure about this type of grouping functions exist in version 1 but I’ll try this today

Comment: @rajatsethi This type of grouping requires XSLT 2.0 or higher. If you are limited to XSLT 1.0, then do not add `xslt-2.0` and `xslt-3.0` tags to your questions.