# Can we add regex or any pattern filter on id attribute in xslt 1.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

FYI: Here i used p tags but id attribute can be present in any tag.
I'm using a pattern `[0-9a-fA-F]{24}` to allow just these kind of object id's. This pattern says that id should contain only 24 characters from 0-9 numbers and a-f alphabets.
If any tag contains id attribute which does not match the above pattern/regex then i want to replace that id with just empy space. There are many other tags in my xml so that tags should not be deleted and should display as it is.
I have a xml like below

```
   <root>
    <p id = "623cbd63ed6cdf6ecba73c21"> some text </p>
    <p id = "623cbd63ed6cdf6ecba73c27"> some text </p>
    <p id = "244c601f7498439a81b4dac0545fc7ea"> some text </p>
    <p id = "abcasa"> some text </p>
    <ol> some text <li>list</li>
    </ol>
    <b> some text </b>
    </root>
```

Desired output:

```
<root>
    <p id = "623cbd63ed6cdf6ecba73c21"> some text </p>
    <p id = "623cbd63ed6cdf6ecba73c27"> some text </p>
    <p id = ""> some text </p>
    <p id = ""> some text </p>
    <ol> some text <li>list</li>
    </ol>
    <b> some text </b>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title says XSLT 1.0 but you also added the `xslt-2.0` tag. Please make it clear which version you can use - and do this with all your questions regarding XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257k IMy bad. I removed the tag from xslt-2.0

Comment: This is not the first time you do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800410/add-ol-ul-to-all-li-tags-that-doesnt-have-ol-ul-as-its-parent-xslt#comment126891584_71802331  Please don't do it again, it wastes everybody's time.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sure will take care for all my future question. Actually i started new here and i really need some help related to xslt that's why i tag all xslt but now i'll take care of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for regex in XSLT 1.0 (unless your specific processor supports it through an extension function).

In this case, you can do without:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@id[translate(., '0123456789ABCDEFabcdef', '') or string-length(.) !=24]">
    <xsl:attribute name="id"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried with this but this xsl is removing all other tags that exist in my xml except p tag. There are other tags which still i need as it is. I have edited the desired output as well. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @rajatsethi We work with the example you provide. Try the other option I have added.

Comment: @michail.hor257k tried the other option as well but it doesn't delete the value inside id(like ths id="") if it doesnot matches the pattern. tried some other ways but that doesn't help

Comment: I am getting the expected result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVK6D5B

Comment: If possible can you give your suggestions for my question. Thanks in advance.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71884294/move-parent-id-attribute-to-its-first-child-if-id-matches-the-given-filter-xslt

Answer (score 0):

Well, XPath 2.0 and therefore XSLT 2.0 and later have a `matches` function so your regular expression would need to be "anchored" with i.e. `^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$` but otherwise you can use e.g. `<xsl:template match="@id[not(matches(., '^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$'))]"><xsl:attribute name="{name()}"/></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but your solution will not work for xslt 1.0 as it does not provide matches() function

Comment: @rajatsethi, well, don't post questions tagged as xslt-2.0 to later remove that tag once you got an answer for that version.

Comment: Sorry for the confussion related to version 2. My bad that I tag xslt 2 but my question is for xslt 1