# Move parent id attribute to it's first child if id matches the given filter XSLT 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to move the id attribute of ol/ul tag to it's first li tag child only if value of the id has correct objectId pattern like [0-9a-fA-F]{24} which means id should only contain `0123456789ABCDEFabcdef` and length should be 24. If id is not valid then remove that id attribute from ul/ol tag and if id is correct then move it to it's first child and change it's name to OID.
Thanks in advance.
My xml:

```
<root>
   <ul id="623dcc9772fc494aa2252885">
      <li>Donate the shelters so animals can be homed easier.</li>
      <li>If you see a dog on the road, take it to a shelter</li>
   </ul>
      <ul id="623dcc9772fc494aa2252gghghghgg885">
      <li>Donate the shelters so animals can be homed easier.</li>
      <li>If you see a dog on the road, take it to a shelter</li>
   </ul>
</root>
```

Desired output:

```
<root>
   <ul>
      <li OID="623dcc9772fc494aa2252885">Donate the shelters so animals can be homed easier. 
      </li>
      <li>If you see a dog on the road, take it to a shelter</li>
   </ul>
      <ul>
      <li>Donate the shelters so animals can be homed easier.</li>
      <li>If you see a dog on the road, take it to a shelter</li>
   </ul>
</root>
```

What i tried:

```
<xsl:template match="li[not(@id)][1]">
        <li>
            <xsl:if test="ancestor::ul[1]/@id != '' or ancestor::ol[1]/@id != '' ">
                <xsl:attribute name="oid">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="ancestor::ol[1]/@id != ''">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ol[1]/@id"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="ancestor::ul[1]/@id != ''">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ul[1]/@id"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
             <!--do not forget to copy possible other attributes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
```

But this also add that id which doesnot match my filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.  Let me know, if you have questions.

```
<xsl:template match="ul">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="translate(@id, '0123456789ABCDEFabcdef', '') = ''
                    and string-length(@id) = 24">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="li[1]" mode="move">
          <xsl:with-param name="id" select="@id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="li[position() &gt; 1]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--  ************* move mode ******************-->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="move">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="move"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li" mode="move">
  <xsl:param name="id"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="not(boolean(@id))">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="move"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't know what {24} in your requirement means but you can always use the sting-length() function to test the length of the string.

Comment: But u didn't check the length of id that should be 24.

Comment: I added the test of string length.  This should do it.  Also, I did this is 1.0.  If you are using higher version, you can use your regular expressions.  But, it's really not necessary.

Comment: really thanks for your input but i forgot to add in my question that only add id to it's child if it don't contains the id attribute. Can you suggest that

Comment: I made the change you wanted.  Please click the up arrow next to the answer to close out the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996195/verify-href-has-a-valid-url-or-not-xslt-1?noredirect=1#comment127219728_71996195

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
<xsl:template match="li[not(@id)][1]">
    <li>
        <xsl:if test="ancestor::ul[1]/@id != '' or ancestor::ol[1]/@id != ''">
            <!--<xsl:attribute name="bulb-id">-->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="ancestor::ol[1]/@id != '' and translate(ancestor::ol[1]/@id, '0123456789ABCDEFabcdef', '') = '' and string-length(ancestor::ol[1]/@id) = 24">
                        <xsl:attribute name="bulb-id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ol[1]/@id"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="ancestor::ul[1]/@id != '' and translate(ancestor::ul[1]/@id, '0123456789ABCDEFabcdef', '') = '' and string-length(ancestor::ul[1]/@id) = 24">
                        <xsl:attribute name="bulb-id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ul[1]/@id"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            <!--</xsl:attribute>-->
        </xsl:if>
        <!-- do not forget to copy possible other attributes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove @id from ol, ul (but only when it contains li in it's child) -->
<xsl:template match="ol[li]/@id | ul[li]/@id"/>
```

Comment: Looks like Michael Kay answered that for you.  He literally wrote the book...  XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0...  Lucky for you.